# Include Google api client in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I am using [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) library for Google Analytic, when i used it in simple php file its work fine. Here is code

```
<?php 
include_once "templates/base.php";
session_start();
set_include_path("../src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';
$client_id = '';
$client_secret = '';
$redirect_uri = '';
$apikey='';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setDeveloperKey($apikey);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics');
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $client->revokeToken();
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $b = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
  print_r($b->refresh_token);
  $client->refreshToken($b->refresh_token);
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
?>
```

But when i used in wordpress plugin it give many errors for file includes. How i can include file in wordpress plugin? here is WordPress code for include the file

```
class postAnalytics
{
    public function __construct()
    {
            require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';
    }
```

}

Here is error

> Warning: require_once(Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\post-analytics-new\Google\Client.php
>   on line 18
>    when i explore the directory file is there but problem with include the file.

Comment: Yes its work fine in simple php file giving error only in wordpress plugin...

Comment: I just found the problem and now code is working no need to answer ...

here is the code i just put at the top of page

    set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__) . '/src/');

Comment: can you show the entire code to help me out?

Answer (score 1):

First check the naming conventions

if is the folder **Google** or **google** and is the file **Client.php** or **client.php**

if everything is correct, Try this:

```
$file = glob(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)."Google/Client.php";
include_once $file;
```

and if you are using a template, use:

```
get_template_part()
```

WordPress now offers a function, get_template_part(), that is part of the native API and is used specifically for reusing sections - or templates - of code (except for the header, footer, and sidebar) through your theme.

Comment: Thanks for you time and suggestion but i found the problem and solved it

Comment: @khubbaibNaeem, Great to hear! Please edit your question which would help any other person to figure out what could be the issues